# UINavigationBar color is getting change after pushing a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationcontroller

I'm facing a wired issue related to navigation bar color. Please check below images.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Image 1 is a home view controller and image 2 is a second view controller that I'm pushing on home view controller.

In `AppDelegate.swift` I have set following...

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Color.red
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage();
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Please watch till end the below image you will get an idea about issue. I've reduced animation speed so you can get an idea about it.

[image]

Please help me out this issue. Any help will be appreciated !!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because both ViewController have different backgroundColor of UIView (in your case black & white)

Comment: I have set global color to navigation bar in app delegate

Comment: Check whether both the view controller has same baground, because one' background is dark that's why it is getting dark red (translucent proerty). Or you can uncheck the translucent property of UINavigationBar.

Comment: Add this line in appDelegate UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

Comment: @JD. your solution is working...thanks

Comment: I'm wondering that I have also tried tried this thing but that was not working...but now its working fine...don't know what was the issue...

Comment: Yeah, sometimes mixing all things.. Its happen. Happy coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncheck the translucent property of UINavigationBar as below-

[image]

**OR**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```